# Process elements in chunks using multiprocessing queues

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, python-3.8

I have a multiprocessing queue; The end of the queue is signaled by using a SENTINEL value, a string.

```
aq =  Queue()
```

........................

The instance in the queue are of class A:

```
class A:
 id: str
 desc: str
```

In a function I'm getting elements from the queue `aq` and process them in chunks.
The first element(if is just one) can be a SENTINEL, nothing to process.
....

```
def process:
  chunk_data = []
  all = [
  item = aq.get()
  if not isinstance(item, A):
    return
  chunk_data.append(item.id)
  while item != SENTINEL:
   # start process in chunks
   # adding elements to the chunk list until is full
    while len(chunk_data) < CHUNK_MAX_SIZE: # 50
      item = aq.get()
      if item == SENTINEL:
        break
      chunk_data.append(item.id)
    # the chunk list is full start processing
    chunk_process_ids = process_data(chunk_data) # process chunks
    all.extend(chunk_process_ids)
    # empty chunk list and start again
    chunk_data.clear()
```

The function works as expected but I consider the code to be convoluted. I'm looking for a simple, clearer version.

Comment: That function doesn't work. It's not even syntactically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interest of following the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), here's what I believe is a cleaner version of your code with no repetition of logics. Note that it's generally better to handle errors by raising an exception than to simply return when the type of an input value is not as expected.

```
def process():
    all = []
    while True:
        chunk_data = []
        for _ in range(CHUNK_MAX_SIZE):
            if (item := aq.get()) == SENTINEL:
                break
            assert isinstance(item, A)
            chunk_data.append(item.id)
        if chunk_data:
            all.extend(process_data(chunk_data))
        if len(chunk_data) < CHUNK_MAX_SIZE:
            break
```

You can also clean up the code a bit further with [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) if you don't need to validate if each item is of type `A` (which you shouldn't anyway if you have control over the code that enqueues items):

```
from itertools import islice
from operator import attrgetter

def process():
    all = []
    data = iter(aq.get, SENTINEL)
    while True:
        chunk_data = list(map(attrgetter('id'), islice(data, CHUNK_MAX_SIZE)))
        if chunk_data:
            all.extend(process_data(chunk_data))
        if len(chunk_data) < CHUNK_MAX_SIZE:
            break
```

Credit to @KellyBundy for a more concise version as commented below:

```
from itertools import islice
from operator import attrgetter

def process():
    all = []
    data = iter(aq.get, SENTINEL)
    ids = map(attrgetter('id'), data)
    while chunk_ids := list(islice(ids, CHUNK_MAX_SIZE)):
        all += process_data(chunk_ids)
```

Comment: Taking that a little further: [code](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVDRSsMwFGU-5isu-LBEpyi-yGDgkIFDHcgURJES2nQLpk2WpIjf4steFPylfY03Sde5PrQ9yT3nnnO-fsynX-p6vekNDmEufGOg1Ba8cF7WC1JaXcGqEY0AWRltPTwEkM4L7nmuuHPCbW-7I3K1-41vGA8J4COLIcjak_lk9jidTe5gBH0natwmVJ_wFeK4gjISjEgvKpyHI8vrhaDnZ2wAW2oS5KtT03iaBsuW4LohEMoJGMd7xsj1zdPsNrsfP2fz6csEl12QQpRgrM6Fc1kwTWXhWNI2Fq1GHKHFfmyNEdx348uTy03vIBaB2tZrrboapFMyb1vSRljuQ5R0x723C-GRQv6vpu1KrhS6en2LINhBFPQp5kTaLj1r63Q4UHFDd7q0L4s-9hTYaepjKZWAfNnU71lgDEegpMNk0WcIOID9ZlhrZ2vpeLTfUafFUhW_XYyE1-v0_QM)

Comment: [Modded code](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZHNSgMxEMfpNU8x4KG7UoviRRYKVilY1IJUQbyUdHe2G8h-NJlF-ixeelHwlfo0TpJ2W3PYzXz_5p-vn2ZDRV1td73BGcyR2gby2gChJVWtRG7qEtYttgiqbGpD8OKM4M8kyVRLa9Eeop1L3B6v_gvjRAAflSWgKhLzyex1Ops8wQj6Fiuehrov5JptPyKKhQNRhCXnw7mR1Qqjq8t4AIfS0FCuh01LUUjM9wW2SwLUFmHs43Es7h_eZo-L5_H7Yj79mPCwa5FhDo2pU7R24aAjldk49G4Mo3rbm4b1MRWvYL9byi9udr07LwT3NlTXupNBWa1SHEBaSFUFseoGjSS3UUiRRGaFxJXCEywlpQVmjtPIpebiag-hiDGdu4sFms9CaQx1kIxAK8uofjAnuvJ9vTsbhToLueJ04ShOIKioNex7eOihg14cBkalbKJTjQYdr4scd4n6KuvzE3lcfhn2Ht8r5sB__WM-QcrfDijY2234_wE)

Comment: Heh, even I wouldn't go as far as using `chain` here :-). I'd only use `for chunk_ids in batched(ids, CHUNK_MAX_SIZE):` instead of the `while ...:`.

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to structure the code as follows:

```py
def get_chunks():
    chunk_data = []
    while True:
        item = aq.get()
        if item == SENTINEL: # or: if not isinstance(item A):
            break
        chunk_data.append(item.id)
        if len(chunk_data) == CHUNK_MAX_SIZE:
            yield chunk
            chunk_data = []
    # Do we have a "small" chunk?
    if chunk_data:
        yield chunk_data

def process():
    all = []
    for chunk_data in get_chunks():
        all.extend(process_data(chunk_data))
```

**But it would be preferable for the "writer" to use `get_chunks` so that it is already-made chunks being written to the queue. This would result in fewer (but larger) queue accesses, which *in general* would be more efficient.**

Here is an example where I am assuming that all the `A` instances are in a list, `list_of_a_instances`:

```py
def get_chunks():
    chunk_data = []
    for item in list_of_a_instances: # a list of all the A instances, for example
        chunk_data.append(item.id)
        if len(chunk_data) == CHUNK_MAX_SIZE:
            yield chunk
            chunk_data = []
    # Do we have a "small" chunk?
    if chunk_data:
        yield chunk_data

def process():
    all = []
    while True:
        chunk_data = aq.get()
        if chunk_data == SENTINEL:
            break
        all.extend(process_data(chunk_data))

def writer():
    for chunk_data in get_chunks():
        aq.put(chunk_data)
    aq.put(SENTINEL)
```